# Tengo problemas con Font Awesome

Tags: font-awesome

Hola he descargado font awentsome coloque la hoja de estilos de la siguiente manera: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">` tengo la carpeta "webfonts" al mismo nivel del index. Pero no me muestra los iconos. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Indicanos como está definida la estrucutura de tu proyecto y como estás llamando a los íconos en el html. Saludos

Comment: Pone la estructura del proyecto, por otro lado abri font-wesome, en parte del codigo declara que llama a un archivo ttf que es la fuente, ahi tenes que tener bien direccionado donde esta el archivo de las fuentes.

Comment: así como lo describes lo mas probable es que sea un problema de rutas, comparte la estructura de tus capetas como ya te lo han pedido

Answer (score 1):

Descarga el archivo de Font desde este Link:

```
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself
```

Ejemplo de la web:

```
<head>
 <link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--load all 
 styles -->
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fas fa-user"></i> <!-- uses solid style -->
  <i class="far fa-user"></i> <!-- uses regular style -->
  <i class="fal fa-user"></i> <!-- uses light style -->
  <!--brand icon-->
  <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i> <!-- uses brands style -->
</body>
```

Ejemplo que hice recien poniendole la carpeta donde esta el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo all.css al final tiene las fuentes ahi tenes que ver que este bien redireccionado a la carpeta webFonts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahi ya funcionan los iconos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]